# Sequence of critical points converging to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I would like an example of a function with the following properties,

> A differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $0$ is the limit of a sequence of critical points of $f$, and $f'(0)>0$.

The examples I was able to think of, always fail to be differentiable at $0$, would anyone have any idea of an example?

I believe that the function must oscillate infinitely times close to $0$ so that it is possible to create the sequence of critical points, so I am finding it difficult to think of a function that is differentiable at zero, because in its neighborhood, the function is strange.

$c$ is a critical point if $f'(c)=0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x+x^2\sin \frac{1}{x},\qquad & x \ne 0,
\\
0,\qquad & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
[image: graph]

---

**addd**

The derivative exists at zero.
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} 1+ x \sin\frac{1}{x} = 1 .
$$
But the derivative is not continuous at zero.

Comment: I thought in this function, but it is differentiable in $0$? If it is, $f'(0)=0$?

Comment: But I think the function $x+x^3\sin \frac{1}{x}$ solves.

Comment: $f'(0)=\lim(1+x\sin (1/x))=1$

Comment: @zkutch the derivative is $1 - \cos(1/x) + 2 x \sin(1/x)$

Comment: It's for $x\ne 0$. Consider direct definition for $x=0$.

Comment: @zkutch You're right, thanks!